# Unused Entity issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting "Unused Entity Issue" warning from following code at line number 4(for logout variable). But I am using that. So how come it is unused ?

```
        NSString *actionSheetTitle = @"xxxx";
        NSString *tour = @"xxxx";
        NSString *feedBack = @"xxxx";
        NSString *logout = @"Log Out";

        #ifdef XXXX
            UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                          initWithTitle:actionSheetTitle
                                          delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@""
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:tour, feedBack, logout, nil];
            [actionSheet setCancelButtonIndex:3];
        #else

            UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                          initWithTitle:actionSheetTitle
                                          delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@""
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                          otherButtonTitles:tour, feedBack, nil];

            [actionSheet setCancelButtonIndex:2];
        #endif

    }
```

Comment: does XXXX is really defined ? if not the else block will only be visible and thus the logout entity will be considered unused

Comment: solved it by putting NSString *logout = @"Log Out"; below ifdef XXXX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the else condition You are not using the "logout".

Answer (score 1):

when you are using #ifdef and #else the Xcode is "hiding" one of the sections.

That's why it does't consider it as a part pif the code and aware you.